# Stripe payment in INR (Indian rupee) issue

Tags: stripe-payments

I am testing stripe payment gateway. If I try to pay in INR (Indian rupee), the amount is not converting to US dollar correctly. In my code if I debug using break points I get the amount is **610** and currency code is **INR** but while processing the payment I get error stating :

```
com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Amount must convert to at least 50 cents. ₹6.10 converts to approximately $0.09.
```

It should be ₹610.00 but its taking ₹6.10. I am not able to figure it out why? Is this a bug in stripe?

Comment: For non-zero-decimal currencies, amounts in Stripe's API need to passed in cents, so if you want to charge ₹610.00, you need to pass the value `61000`.

Comment: the application i am testing can accept the currency from many countries. So do I need to write custom code to convert the currency like Indian rupee (INR) to paise (where 1 INR = 100 paise)? Doesn't Stripe handle it internally?

Comment: You need not to multiply by 100 (in cent) for the mentioned currencies at https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-zero-decimal-currencies-does-stripe-support otherwise you have to multiply the amount by 100 for non-zero-decimal currencies. The passing amount must be an integer value.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a stripe bug. It is a stripe feature. Basically this error is shown because the minimum amount required for a transaction in stripe is 50 cents. Stripe asks you to convert your amount into the lowest denomination no matter what currency type you were using. Just convert the amount in the smallest part of money. for e.g.,
 In 1 rupee there is 100 paisa. So when you charge the 610 INR stripe take this as in paisa not in rupees. So you have to multiply the amount by 100, i.e., 610 * 100 (1 INR )